# Oracle Query string to number conversion issue

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with 3 columns

```
emp_id  number
fname  string
pnumber string
```

In some cases emp_id and pnumber are the same. I am trying to query the table using

```
select * from emp where emp_id = pnumber
```

it is throwing an error; Invalid number

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because not all data in the column `pnumber` is a NUMBER. Oracle is implicitly converting this column to a number in order to perform the comparison.

You need to *explicitly* convert the `emp_id` column to a string using [`TO_CHAR()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions201.htm#SQLRF06130):

```
select * from emp where to_char(emp_id) = pnumber
```

More generally, [*never* rely on implicit conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements002.htm#SQLRF51046); always do everything explicitly so the database know what you're trying to do. To quote:

> Oracle recommends that you specify explicit conversions, rather than rely on implicit or automatic conversions, for these reasons:
>
> - SQL statements are easier to understand when you use explicit data type conversion functions.
> - Implicit data type conversion can have a negative impact on    performance, especially if the data type of a column value is converted to that of a constant rather than the other way around.
> - Implicit conversion depends on the context in which it occurs and may not work the same way in every case. For example, implicit conversion from a datetime value to a VARCHAR2 value may return an unexpected year depending on the value of the NLS_DATE_FORMAT
>     parameter.
> - Algorithms for implicit conversion are subject to change across software releases and among Oracle products. Behavior of explicit conversions is more predictable.